# R : Cut function with repeated bounds, sort of bigram

Tags: r, split, cut

It looks like a very noob question but I can't find a solution.
I got a big ordered vector like

```
vector_example=c(55,65,89, 98)
```

And I want to build a matrix like

```
55 65
65 89
89 98
```

How would you do that?

Comment: With `embed(vector_example, 2)[, 2:1]`.  But you could also do `matrix(rep(x, c(1, rep(2, length(x)-2), 1)), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)`

Comment: wow awesome, fast and efficient!! Did not know that function. Thanks

Comment: `cbind(x[-length(x)], x[-1])` also works for this example